# How to implement daylight savings for a different time zone in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I am getting time zone

```
time_String = GetTimeZoneDisplayName(enum_timezone);
```

`time_String` is a particular timezone. In order to add daylight to particular time zone, last argument should be positive in below function. How to decide which time zone is having daylight savings?

```
setenv( "TZ", time_String, 0(No Daylight)/+ve (Daylight is there );
```

Comment: Boost date time has all this stuff.

Comment: I am expecting answer in C.

Comment: In which case your tagging is rather suspect. You could always build a shared object in C++ using boost and link that to your C code. It would be boring to implement this stuff yourself.

Answer (score 0):

(Moved from comment)

Unless I misunderstand the question, this is usually done using [tzset()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tzset). The [glibc docs cover this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Time-Zone-Functions.html), including why it is usually not necessary to call this yourself:

> **Function: void tzset (void)**
>
> *Preliminary: | MT-Safe env locale | AS-Unsafe heap lock | AC-Unsafe lock mem fd | See POSIX Safety Concepts.*
>
> The tzset function initializes the tzname variable from the value of the TZ environment variable. It is not usually necessary for your program to call this function, because it is called automatically when you use the other time conversion functions that depend on the time zone.

It sets the environment variables the way you want as well as populating the tzname and setting DST (if the timezone has it).

Comment: tzset() if we will invoke automatically will set time zone and daylight saving value. But My question is if we asked to set particular time zone? we have to find whether that particular time zone supports daylight saving or not.

Comment: How to decide whether a particular time zone support daylight saving or not in c/Linux.